# Can the list view threshold be configured for a specific content database, instead of for a web application?

Tags: web-application, list-view-threshold

The List View Threshold is configured via Central Administration for a specific web application. If I have more than one content database for a given web application, is it possible to have separate list view theshold settings for each content database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is a Web Application setting and it can't be configured based on Content Databases.

Using PowerShell this setting can be changed as

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication $siteURL
$webApp.MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation = 5000
$webApp.MaxItemsPerThrottledOperationOverride = $true
$webApp.MaxItemsPerThrottledOperationWarningLevel = 2000
$webApp.MaxListItemRowStorage = 8
$webApp.MaxQueryLookupFields = 0
$webApp.DailyStartUnthrottledPrivilegedOperationsHour = 17
$webApp.DailyStartUnthrottledPrivilegedOperationsMinute = 0
$webApp.DailyUnthrottledPrivilegedOperationsDuration = 1
$webApp.IsBackwardsCompatible = [Microsoft.SharePoint.TriState]::false
$webApp.ChangeLogExpirationEnabled = $false
$webApp.Update()
```

As you can see there is not option to specify Content Database

Comment: If I have 2 separate content databases within a single web application and I execute a query that exceeds the list view threshold on a list that exists in one of the two content databases, will both content databases be affected (locked) or just the content database for which the list exists in?

Comment: Just the content database which the list exists.